# Generate a QR code when creating a new WordPress user

Tags: php, hooks, users, profiles

I know that you can use the `show_user_profile`, `edit_user_profile`, `personal_options_update` and `edit_user_profile_update` to add and manage additional fields in user profiles.

In a site I'm developing, I need to add a new field in user profiles to store a QR code that unambiguously identifies a user when creating it. My question is, is there an easy way to generate a QR code when adding a new user to a WordPress site? If so, how? Do I need any external lib or something? Any suggestions?

```
function save_qrcode_user_profile_field( $user_id ) {
    if ( empty( $_POST['_wpnonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'update-user_' . $user_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { 
        return false; 
    }

    // Here I need to generate a QR code that represents this user

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'qrcode', $generated_qrcode );
}
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_qrcode_user_profile_field' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_qrcode_user_profile_field' );
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: WordPress doesn't have any built-in QR Code functionality. This is something you'd have to build out yourself or find a plugin that does this. It's not clear what the QR code is supposed to do.

Comment: The QR code would be used for access control to enter a physical venue.

Comment: this is likely going to be entirely custom and outside what WordPress can do out of the box.